# Merging DataGridView cells if has the same value error

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to merge DataGridView cells if they have the same value. Everything looks OK but if I click more than 2 Checkboxes . It displayed the error as this picture:
[image]

```
 private void grdDNSELECT_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
            if (e.RowIndex < 1 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
                return;
            e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex) ? DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None : grdDNSELECT.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Top;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void grdDNSELECT_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.RowIndex == 0)
                return;
            if (IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex))
            {

                e.Value = "";
                e.FormattingApplied = true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
           //
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do not say at which line this error is thrown. I am guessing it’s from the line: `e.Value = "";`. It is unclear what `IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)` is doing, however, if one of the columns is a number type then `e.Value=””;` will throw a data error on this assignment. Since this line is in the `CellFormatting` event, this value could possibly be set for any cell… depending on what `IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)` is returning.

Comment: bool IsTheSameCellValue(int column, int row)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell1 = grdDNSELECT[column, row];
            DataGridViewCell cell2 = grdDNSELECT[column, row - 1];
            if (cell1.Value == null || cell2.Value == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return cell1.Value.ToString() == cell2.Value.ToString();
        }

Comment: It may have been better to edit your current question with the added code. Even with the supplied code, I will reiterate. The line `e.Value = "";` will throw this error when it tries to leave the `CellFormatting` event. Using the posted picture as an example: If `IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)` returns true AND `e.ColumnIndex == 0`… then you will get this `DataError` because you cannot set a data grid view check box cell’s value to “”. As stated before the same applies to numeric columns and possibly dates.

Comment: So, where must I edit the code to get rid of this error? I must use checkbox that is my problem. But until now I have no idea to fix it. Please help me with code if possible.

Comment: It appears you have your answer. Keep in mind this also applies to numeric data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved thsi problem by adding condition :

```
private void grdDNSELECT_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == 0|| e.ColumnIndex==0)
            return;
        if (IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex))
        {

            e.Value = "";
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
       //
    }
}
```